# How do I inject a javascript module into a webpage via firefox webextension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

My extension's content script:

```js
let s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute("async", "");
s.setAttribute("type", "module");
s.setAttribute("src", "https://gamergirlandco.github.io/some_script.js");
s.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous")
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

However, I get this error:

```
WebExtension content scripts may only load modules with moz-extension URLs and not: “https://gamergirlandco.github.io/some_script.js”.
```

I've tried adding `*://gamergirlandco.github.io/*` to the `permissions` array in `manifest.json`, but that didn't work.

Help?

Comment: You need to create this script element in [page context](/a/9517879). In Firefox this can be also done via `wrappedJSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

- The injection of script will be subject to the webpage's CSP (Content Security Policy) which means it might not be allowed by the webpage
- Permission needed for the webpage/site that you are trying to inject the script into